# Плотность экранов android

Tags: android

Как правильно подготовить картинки для разных плотностей экрана?
Вот два экрана: 768x1280 и 1200x1900 и оба берут картинки с папки drawable-xhdpi. У первого почти места не хватает, а у другого все отлично отображает. Как сделать, чтобы на первом экране картинки выглядели как на втором? Использую RelativeLayout. Картинки размещены относительно друг от друга.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/bgd"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/google"
    android:id="@+id/btnGoogle" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gmusic"
    android:id="@+id/btnGMusic"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gmail"
    android:id="@+id/btnGMail"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnBook"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnBook"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnBook"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gbook"
    android:id="@+id/btnBook"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gplay"
    android:id="@+id/btnGPlay"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gmaps"
    android:id="@+id/btnGMaps"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnGPlay"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnGPlay"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Думаю для вашего случая достаточно будет установить атрибут `android:padding` (`paddingLeft`, `paddingTop` и тд. в случае разных отступов сверху, снизу и сбоку) для корневого `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Для 768x1280

```
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
```

Для 1200x1900

```
drawable-xlarge-hdpi
```